# Conversion from unique_ptr to non scalar type, when subclass publicly inherits

Tags: c++, inheritance, unique-ptr

I know this is a common error, but im confused as to why it is happening in my current case. My subclass inherits publicly from my superclass, and I have a virtual destructor. The docs on unique_ptr say that it is possible to convert from sub to superclass.

I am receiving this error:

```
conversion from ‘unique_ptr<Multiplication,default_delete<Multiplication>>’ to non-scalar type ‘unique_ptr<Expression,default_delete<Expression>>’ requested
```

This is the base class:

```
typedef unique_ptr<Expression> ExpressionPtr;

class Expression {

    protected:

        bool sign;

        ExpressionPtr root;

        ExpressionPtr exponent;

        ExpressionPtr parentExpression;

        string expressionString;

    public:

        Expression();

        Expression(bool sign, ExpressionPtr& root, ExpressionPtr& exponent);

        virtual ~Expression();
```

This is the subclass:

```
class Multiplication : public Expression {

    private:

        vector<ExpressionPtr> operands;

    public:

        Multiplication();

        Multiplication(bool sign, ExpressionPtr& root, ExpressionPtr& exponent, vector<ExpressionPtr>& operands);
```

and the line that causes the error:

```
ExpressionPtr expanded = make_unique<Multiplication>();
```

I feel like I have done everything correctly, any advice appreciated, cheers :)

Comment: Causes what error? Please include it in the question, and optimally edit your code to create an SSCCE.

Comment: There's nothing really wrong in the code you've shown, but there can be hundreds of others errors that could have happened, include the error message so we can say more.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] it works for me https://godbolt.org/z/nzrxov looks like your code has some lines in wrong order (this `typedef .. ExpressionPtr` is defined before `Expression`).